# How do you place data from different years on the same graph?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a graph which is broken down in both months and years. I'd like to keep the monthly breakdown, however I want to keep them on the same yearly axis.

[This is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6WzE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Year from the columns shelf and place in the color pill. You'll have months along the X axis and 4 different colored lines.